# How to save and edit a Jupyter notebook in a host directory using official Tensorflow docker container?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I want to use the official [Tensorflow docker images](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker) to create and edit a Jupyter notebook stored on the host.

I'm a little confused with what switches I need to provide.  To run a Tensorflow script on the host the docs suggest:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/tmp -w /tmp tensorflow/tensorflow python ./script.py
```

..and to run the Jupyter service:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3-jupyter
```

When I try merging the switches to run Jupyter + mount the host volume:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/tmp -w /tmp -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3-jupyter
```

...its still accessing notebooks stored in the container, not the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notebooks are stored inside the container /tf folder, so copying your files there will do the trick:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $PWD:/tf  -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3-jupyter
```

The first command you mentioned is used to run a **TensorFlow program** developed on the host machine, not a notebook.